# Do these conditions guarantee differentiability at the endpoints?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

$\def\R{\mathbf{R}}$
Let $f:[a,b]\to\R$ be a continuous function, that also happens to be differentiable on $(a,b)$. What additional hypotheses must we make to guarantee differentiability on all of $[a,b]$?
I first thought the above statement would suffice but the sqrt function, $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,2]$ is a counterexample.
My current theory is that by strengthening the hypothesis to say that: if the limit

$$ \lim_{x\to b}{f'(x)}$$ exists, then we can conclude $f$ is differentiable at $b$, and the value of the above limit is indeed equal to $f'(b)$. I don't know how to prove this, but this feels plausible to me. An analogous result should hold for the other endpoint, $a$.
Prove or disprove? in the case of disprove, what additional constraints must we make?

Comment: Existance of $ \lim_{x\to b}{f'(x)}$ and existence of $f'(b)$ are nor related.

Comment: What is, for you, differentiability in a non interior point?

Answer (score 0):

Well,By Lagrange Mean Value Theorem,
Let$x\in（a,b）$，then there exist $ξ_{x}\in（x，b）$ st.
$\frac{f（b）-f（x）}{b-x}=f’（ξ_{x}）$
.Note that $ξ_{x} \to b- $ as $x \to b-$.
Since $lim_{x \to b-} f’（x）$exists，$lim_{x\to b-} f’（ξ_{x}）=lim_{x\to b-} f’（x）$.